# Compress command fails on fresh installation of WireCloud

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I cannot set up a basic wirecloud instance anymore. I tried to create a minimum Wirecloud instance like this:

```
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install wirecloud
wirecloud-admin startproject prj
cd prj/
python manage.py collectstatic
python manage.py compress --force
```

Upon the call to compress the static files an error is thrown:

```
CommandError: An error occurred during rendering /opt/wc/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wirecloud/defaulttheme/templates/wirecloud/views/base_plain.html: Error parsing expression at 30:
    none if($important, !important)
                                  ^

on line 2 of theme/wirecloud.defaulttheme/css/base/z-depth.scss
Traceback:
  File "/opt/wc/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scss/calculator.py", line 167, in parse_expression
    ast = getattr(parser, target)()
  File "/opt/wc/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scss/grammar/expression.py", line 110, in goal
    expr_lst = self.expr_lst()
  File "/opt/wc/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scss/grammar/expression.py", line 199, in expr_lst
    expr_slst = self.expr_slst()
  File "/opt/wc/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scss/grammar/expression.py", line 211, in expr_slst
    or_expr = self.or_expr()
  File "/opt/wc/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scss/grammar/expression.py", line 216, in or_expr
    and_expr = self.and_expr()
  File "/opt/wc/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scss/grammar/expression.py", line 225, in and_expr
    not_expr = self.not_expr()
  File "/opt/wc/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scss/grammar/expression.py", line 236, in not_expr
    comparison = self.comparison()
  File "/opt/wc/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scss/grammar/expression.py", line 244, in comparison
    a_expr = self.a_expr()
  File "/opt/wc/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scss/grammar/expression.py", line 275, in a_expr
    m_expr = self.m_expr()
  File "/opt/wc/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scss/grammar/expression.py", line 290, in m_expr
    u_expr = self.u_expr()
  File "/opt/wc/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scss/grammar/expression.py", line 319, in u_expr
    atom = self.atom()
  File "/opt/wc/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scss/grammar/expression.py", line 359, in atom
    return TernaryOp(expr_lst)
  File "/opt/wc/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scss/ast.py", line 558, in __init__
    raise SyntaxError("if() must have exactly 3 arguments")
SyntaxError: if() must have exactly 3 arguments
```

What is the problem here? I just set up the most basic Wirecloud instance possible. If I do not compress it the same error gets thrown in the browser. Is the latest release of wirecloud broken? Or is it something else?

What do I need to do to get a running version again? Help would be much appreciated since the docker image seems to not be able to get restarted and configurations like other databases and so on are thus not very easy to set up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wirecloud seems to not be ready for pyscss version 1.3.5.
A downgrade via ´pip install -I pyscss==1.3.4` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Use the just released [version 0.9.2 of WireCloud](https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud/releases/tag/0.9.2) :)

See this [github ticket](https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud/issues/202) for more details.

We are also updated the docker images but if you continue have problems using it, please create a [Github ticket](https://github.com/Wirecloud/docker-wirecloud/issues) or create a new question on StackOverflow with the details.